# Join Two Columns from two different files have diffrent number of rows and different headers Unix Shell Script

Tags: linux, shell

I have two file a.txt and b.txt. Both the files are tab delimitated

a.txt has 4 columns and b.txt has 2 columns. a.txt and b.txt has different header names and no of rows are also different. I want to join on Name from a.xt and fruits on b.txt and add it to a.txt. Issue is number of rows keep changing in b.xt sometime new row gets added and some times row gets deleted. so if row get added then that should get added to a.txt and if it gets deleted then should delete from a.txt.

file a.txt

```
Name    09/01   09/02   09/03
Apple   1   2   4
Ornage  3   4   6
Carrot  10  1   7
Lemon   9   8   7
```

file b.xt

```
Fruits  Date
Apple   4
Ornage  8
Carrot  9
Lemon   4
Berries 2
```

Desired output

```
Name    09/01   09/02   09/03   09/04
Apple   1   2   4   4
Ornage  3   4   6   8
Carrot  10  1   7   9
Lemon   9   8   7   4
Berries             2
```

Please help.

Comment: Some info in the output file does not exist in the input file, where `09/04` comes from?

Comment: If two files, like `a.txt` and `b.txt` has one column the same, then you can use `join` to join to file.

Comment: join -o 2.1,1.2,1.3,1.4,1.5,2.3 a.txt b.txt

Comment: @GTwu 09/04 is nothing but Date column from b.txt

Comment: @GTWu I tried join but It is not working as I expected